# Free tool to test mobile apps manually

Tags: manual-testing, mobile

I want to know if there is any free tool available to manually test the mobile apps and mobile websites.

I dont want to use the real devices. Need to emulate the devices

Comment: User 'BrowserStack'  which is free to test web & Mobile apps.  : 
Check below Ref Link-
https://www.browserstack.com/users/sign_in

Comment: well there are very limited options in free trail. But still thank you

Comment: I have tried pcloudy, it is good to use and they are giving free credits as well. I have tried both manual and automation, it is performing well. I have agree with @Ashish, thanks for suggesting pcloudy.com Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> mobile websites.

For the websites, you can usually just resize the browser, and then you will get the mobile website. So any web testing tool will work.

> apps

For Android, there are many android emulators available. Check a list [here](http://www.androidauthority.com/best-android-emulators-for-pc-655308/)

Comment: can you mention the free emulators?

Comment: Here is a good list: http://www.androidauthority.com/best-android-emulators-for-pc-655308/  (I have used Bluestacks in the past)

Comment: Bluestack is good, but it contain soo many advertisements and so many bolt-wares.

Comment: I have seen the most of the tools mentioned here are for gamers. I want to use the tools to test mobile apps and mobile websites. I hope i can still use any one of the tools.

Answer (score 1):

For native mobile apps, [check out AWS mobile farm](https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/).  They have a free tier of 250 minutes per month.  They allow you to "rent" a device for some time.

For mobile web, you can use developer tools in the browsers to set the agent string to your target device.  [Here is a tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/113439/how-to-change-your-browsers-user-agent-without-installing-any-extensions/).

Also, you can test the mobile web through the devices you "rent" from Amazon.

Answer (score 1):

When I was working with an startup where they didn`t had much of resource(device, for test), I did some research and found the good one to test mobile application.
You can check for ***pCloudy***. Various range of devices and for different platforms too. Can perform Manual as well as Automation. Good one to try on.

Comment: This is very good tool. Thanks a ton Ashish.

Answer (score 0):

For testing mobile apps and websites, there are a few free tools:

1. You can install [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/) on my Mac and then download a number of simulators for various iOS devices like iPhone + iPad's, Apple Watch / OS and tvOS.
2. [Sauce Labs](http://saucelabs.com/devices) (and other SaaS testing providers) offer an even larger number of simulators / emulators for a wide range of mobile devices. Sauce Labs has a free (albeit limited) account that you can certainly start with.

Answer (score 0):

Tell me if you want to know more tools or any specific one :)

Best emulators for Android:

- https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html
- https://www.genymotion.com/
- https://www.genymotion.com/
- http://www.bluestacks.com/
- http://www.andyroid.net/
- https://www.visualstudio.com/pl/vs/msft-android-emulator/

To check mobile screen resolutions and metrics:

- https://design.google.com/devices/
- http://viewportsizes.com/

You can also use Mobile Device Lab providers that gives few devices for free

- http://testdroid.com
- http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlDeviceList.action
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/

Answer (score 0):

For Android, use Android Studio and its simulators. Linux and Mac.

For iPhone, use the XCode emulator on a Mac

Also consider:

Browserstack, Sauce Labs and other SAAS (with emulators through a web browser) providers that have a free get started account.

Answer (score 0):

For android ,Best of the best was having a android emulator using AVD manager with the Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM)

Comment: Is it to test both mobile apps and mobile websites?

Comment: Yes ,we can run both native n web